# Can I see rule used for reformat in IDEA IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, styling

Sometimes when reformatting code via CTRL + ALT + S I struggle with finding rule which is the reason for changing my code. Is there any detailed view in any IDEA IDE for this?

Specific example:

Before Reformat:

```
myMethod(){}
```

After Reformat:

```
myMethod(){
}
```

And I kind of have to search through all styling settings.

Comment: `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Code Style` -> Your Code Language ( like `Java`, `HTML` , ....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do the following:

- Select a code fragment
- Press `Alt+Enter` and click `Adjust code style settings`

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#reformat_code for more information